# How to convert a string into datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am writing a SQL query to convert string to datetime:

```
SELECT CAST('2017-04-07.15-23-44' AS datetime)
```

When I am converting it to datetime getting an error

> varchar data type to datetime data type resulted in out of range value.

Comment: That is because it isn't properly formatted to be converted.

Comment: Why are you using strings instead of dates in the first place? Fixing an invalid field or parameter type is far better than covering it up. Besides, I doubt any country on earth uses such a format for date and time. How could SQL Server guess what this string means?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually I am getting this from the filename.

Comment: What name is that? Again, that format isn't used by any country. How could SQL Server guess what it means? If you want to parse this custom format you'll have to write the code for it. It's a lot easier to parse such strings *before* inserting the data into the database

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 outlines the formats supported - and even then you have to specify the format to convert from.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos systemname_bandwidth_2017-04-07.15-23-44.txt kind of name from this I got last part.

Comment: @dfundako can we use replace or charindex to format it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string with the `.` as delimiter and in the 2nd part replace all `'-'` with `':'`.
Concatenate the 2 parts again and then cast it to `DATETIME`:

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(20) = '2017-04-07.15-23-44';

SELECT CAST(LEFT(@d, CHARINDEX('.', @d) - 1) + ' ' +
            REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@d, CHARINDEX('.', @d) + 1, LEN(@d)), '-', ':')
            AS datetime
           )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a9fd3fc291022295fa704f17e0b4e99d).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to format as an ISO date

```
declare @date varchar(20)='2017-04-07.15-23-44' 
select Cast(Replace(Replace(Stuff(Stuff(@date,14,1,':'),17,1,':'),'-',''),'.',' ')  as datetime)
```